# Diferença de resultados entre soma com pivot e soma de contadores

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, programação-estruturada

Olá, eu gostaria de um apoio pra entender porque as duas querys a seguir produzem resultados diferentes. A estratégia que busquei com elas é a mesma, de contar e agrupar resultados de sip com diferentes colunas na tabela, mas tive que optar pela segunda query por conta de performance com um volume alto de dados.
a primeira query é de um pivot na tabela:

```
SELECT 
    id_tabela,
    SUM(CASE WHEN coluna1_sip = x THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'x1',
    SUM(CASE WHEN coluna1_sip = y THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'y1',
    SUM(CASE WHEN coluna1_sip = z THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'z1',
    .
    .
    .
    SUM(CASE WHEN coluna11_sip = x THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'x11'
from tabela group by id_tabela
```

a segunda maneira, abaixo, foi para replicar os resultados acima de uma maneira menos custosa

```
SELECT
    SUM((CASE WHEN coluna1_sip = x THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
        (CASE WHEN coluna2_sip = x then 1 ELSE 0 END) +
        .
        .
        .
        (CASE WHEN coluna11_sip = x then 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS 'x',
    SUM((CASE WHEN coluna1_sip  = y then 1 else 0 end) +
        (CASE WHEN coluna2_sip  = y then 1 else 0 end) +
        .
        .
        .
        (CASE when coluna11_sip = y then 1 else 0 end)) as 'y'
from tabela
```

Gostaria de ajuda para entender porque os resultados da soma da segunda maneira (somando os contadores) não são compatíveis com o da primeira(trazer todos como pivot e somar depois), agradeço imensamente a ajuda.

Comment: Agrupa por "id_tabela" ? No 2º não tem.

Comment: No 2º não foi necessário colocar, mas no primeiro, sim. Vou aproveitar pra editar o primeiro. Mesmo com o agrupamento no 2º não houve diferença no resultado final.

Comment: Seria bom uma amostra dos dados para saber o que você está obtendo e o que esperava obter. Tente criar um modelo no http://sqlfiddle.com/ e edite sua pergunta incluindo a url pra esse modelo, desta forma poderemos simular o problema e a solução.

Comment: Vou criar sim, muito obrigado pela dica, Clarck!